# CKEditor & Webpack: missing loaders

Tags: webpack, ckeditor

I'm trying to add CKEditor5 to my website following this guide: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html

I have done the steps where it tells me to add the loaders. I've not changed anything to what the guide tells you to add to yourwebpack config.

This is my full webpack config:

```
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path'),
    glob = require('glob'),
    ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

var pageEntryArray = glob.sync('./assets/scripts/views/**/*.ts');
var pageEntries = {};
pageEntryArray.forEach(function (item) {
    var ext = path.extname(item);
    var filename = path.basename(item, ext);
    pageEntries[filename] = item;
});

var otherEntries = {
    'init': ['babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', 'element-closest', './assets/scripts/init.ts'],
}

var entries = Object.assign({}, otherEntries, pageEntries);

var cacheLoader = {
    loader: 'cache-loader'
};

var threadLoader = {
    loader: 'thread-loader',
    options: {
        // there should be 1 cpu for the fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
        workers: require('os').cpus().length - 1,
    }
};

var babelLoader = {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        presets: ["es2015", "es2016"]
    }
};

var config = {
    entry: entries,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/js'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    cacheLoader,
                    threadLoader,
                    babelLoader,
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            happyPackMode: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    cacheLoader,
                    threadLoader,
                    babelLoader,
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/,
                use: ['raw-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/[^/]+\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            checkSyntacticErrors: true,
            tslint: false
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            filename: 'common.js',
            minChunks: 2
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

As you can see I've added the loader for .scss files and .svg files, however, when I try to run webpack, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/theme/theme.scss
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (4:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| // For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
| 
| @import '~@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark/theme/theme.scss';
| 
| .ck-editor {
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js 16:0-29
 @ ./assets/scripts/views/project-message/project-message-send.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/theme/icons/redo.svg
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10 16l1-3.982c-3.417 0-8.616.869-10 3.982 0-5.983 6.601-7.96 10-7.96 0-.85-1-3.32-1-4.04l8 6-8 6z" fill="#454545" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/src/undo.js 15:0-47
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js
 @ ./assets/scripts/views/project-message/project-message-send.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/theme/icons/italic.svg
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M13.825 3.914l-.126.558a5.701 5.701 0 0 0-.685.076c-.282.045-.49.088-.626.127-.237.073-.406.186-.508.338a1.586 1.586 0 0 0-.22.5l-2.03 8.769a1.24 1.24 0 0 0-.034.27c.001.13.03.24.086.33.056.09.157.17.304.237.085.04.27.086.558.14.288.053.502.086.643.097l-.127.558H5.656l.127-.558.677-.05c.293-.023.501-.057.625-.102a1.11 1.11 0 0 0 .5-.326c.112-.138.188-.306.228-.503l2.02-8.778a1.428 1.428 0 0 0 .035-.305.59.59 0 0 0-.072-.295c-.048-.085-.148-.161-.3-.229a3.457 3.457 0 0 0-.622-.19 5.001 5.001 0 0 0-.58-.106l.128-.558h5.403z" fill="#454545" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic.js 13:0-51
 @ ./assets/scripts/views/project-message/project-message-send.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/theme/icons/bold.svg
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.135 10.409c.361.248.654.56.88.934.225.375.338.816.338 1.324 0 .609-.128 1.123-.385 1.543-.256.42-.624.751-1.103.994a5.908 5.908 0 0 1-1.755.55c-.663.107-1.442.16-2.338.16H4.539v-.66a22.5 22.5 0 0 0 .66-.076c.265-.033.45-.073.558-.118.208-.085.35-.196.427-.334.076-.138.114-.317.114-.537V5.732c0-.203-.031-.372-.093-.507s-.211-.254-.448-.355a3.326 3.326 0 0 0-.61-.182 14.136 14.136 0 0 0-.608-.114v-.66h6.52c1.64 0 2.825.226 3.552.677.727.45 1.09 1.116 1.09 1.995 0 .406-.08.763-.244 1.07a2.388 2.388 0 0 1-.702.8 4.214 4.214 0 0 1-.99.54c-.383.153-.795.28-1.234.381v.16c.44.046.896.143 1.37.292.473.15.885.343 1.234.58zm-2.723-3.611c0-.665-.187-1.184-.562-1.556-.375-.372-.937-.558-1.687-.558-.107 0-.247.004-.419.012l-.444.021v4.449h.44c.913 0 1.587-.213 2.021-.639.434-.425.651-1.002.651-1.73zm.592 5.759c0-.835-.248-1.475-.744-1.92-.496-.445-1.21-.668-2.14-.668a22.977 22.977 0 0 0-.82.034v4.389c.05.208.209.385.474.528.265.144.586.216.964.216.67 0 1.216-.225 1.636-.676.42-.452.63-1.086.63-1.903z" fill="#454545" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold.js 13:0-47
 @ ./assets/scripts/views/project-message/project-message-send.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/theme/icons/undo.svg
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 10l8 6-1-3.982c3.417 0 8.616.869 10 3.982 0-5.983-6.601-7.96-10-7.96 0-.85 1-3.32 1-4.04l-8 6z" fill="#454545" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/src/undo.js 14:0-47
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js
 @ ./assets/scripts/views/project-message/project-message-send.ts
[11:33:35] Finished 'scripts' after 17 s
Process terminated with code 0.
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "crm.einionmedia.com",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
        "@types/chart.js": "^2.6.2",
        "@types/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.25",
        "@types/flatpickr": "^3.0.2",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.2.10",
        "@types/knockout": "^3.4.44",
        "@types/lodash.flattendeep": "^4.4.2",
        "@types/lodash.groupby": "^4.6.3",
        "@types/lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
        "@types/lodash.orderby": "^4.6.2",
        "@types/numeral": "^0.0.21",
        "@types/select2": "^4.0.38",
        "@types/sortablejs": "^1.3.31",
        "@types/virtual-dom": "^2.0.27",
        "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "cache-loader": "^1.0.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
        "choices.js": "^3.0.2",
        "ckeditor": "^4.7.3",
        "del": "^3.0.0",
        "element-closest": "^2.0.2",
        "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.46",
        "fine-uploader": "^5.15.0",
        "flatpickr": "^3.0.2",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-notifier-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.8",
        "glob": "^7.1.2",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^3.7.0",
        "gulp-cli": "^1.3.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^3.3.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
        "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.1",
        "inputmask": "^3.3.8",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "knockout": "^3.4.2",
        "lodash.flattendeep": "^4.4.0",
        "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
        "lodash.merge": "^4.6.0",
        "lodash.orderby": "^4.6.0",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "numeral": "^2.0.6",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "select2": "^4.0.3",
        "sortablejs": "^1.6.0",
        "thread-loader": "^1.1.1",
        "ts-loader": "^2.3.2",
        "typescript": "^2.4.2",
        "virtual-dom": "^2.1.1",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.5.0",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "node-sass": "^4.6.0",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0"
    }
}
```

Why does Webpack not use the loaders I added in the configuration file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with the `test` for the rules not matching the file names, as per an answer in an issue on CKEditor5 repository: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/139#issuecomment-286551372 - I changed the test regex to match any .svg and .scss files, and now the appropriate loaders are being used.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem for me, at first glance. I ran into this when attempting to import the ImageInsert module, to use with CK5. Simply added a test rule for .svg, to use the raw-loader, and now it compiles without error.